# Input mask visibility

Tags: javascript, maskedinput

I'm currently using the masked input plugin from http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/ on my form. So far it seems to work but I want to modify it so that the mask is displayed at all times and not just when the field is in focus. I was hoping I could just delete a line of code that hides the mask when the field loses focus but it doesn't seem that easy. Does anyone know how to do this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Since you know what the mask is ahead of time, you could always add html5 `placeholder` attributes to the selected `input`s.

Something like

`<input type="text" name="date" placeholder="__/__/____">`

This would appear *greyed out* when the field is not focused but disappear when the field is focused.

See more on `placeholder` text here http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/detect.html#input-placeholder

Comment: Well the field displays the mask when its in focus, so is there not a way to make it do that at all times and not just when it's in focus? I feel like this should be an simple modification I'm just not sure how to do it. Thanks for the quick response.